# UPDATE slow when using FULLTEXT-indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I'm running a simple update query against my `notifications` table:

```
UPDATE `notifications`
SET is_unread = 0
WHERE MATCH(`grouping_string`) AGAINST("f89dc707afa38520224d887f897478a9")
```

The `grouping_string` column has a FULLTEXT index and the `notifications` table has 2M+ rows.

Now, the UPDATE above takes over 70 seconds to execute. However, if I run a SELECT using the same WHERE, the result is immediate.

What might be causing this and how can the UPDATE be optimized?

**Environment:** MySQL 5.6 (InnoDB) on Amazon Aurora engine

**UPDATE:** Using `EXPLAIN` on the query shows that the fulltext index is one of the possible ones to use, but it's not used during execution. Instead, only the PRIMARY (id) is used. Rows affected equals to the number of rows in the table (2M+).

**UPDATE 2**: Result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query%'`:

```
+------------------------------+-----------+
|        Variable_name         |   Value   |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| query_alloc_block_size       | 8192      |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576   |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096      |
| query_cache_size             | 444890112 |
| query_cache_type             | ON        |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF       |
| query_prealloc_size          | 8192      |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: :Are you running the select in mysqlworkbench ?

Comment: Any triggers on that table?

Comment: Do you lock the whole table before performing the update?

Comment: I run the query in PhpMyAdmin but it also takes this long on the website itself. No triggers on the table. No locking either.